# Should I ask my teacher before using speech-to-text software?

Tags: etiquette

Should I ask my teacher before using software of speech-to-text in classes ? The software in question does not record (the audio) at all, just "hear" the input and output text.

What about using it in conferences and lectures ? And is it OK to share this with other students ? I'm more worried about legal issues than anything else (European Union and U.S jurisdictions).

Comment: Related questions: [Is it okay to record audio for a lecture?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/56126/546) and [Under what circumstances would a professor be offended at students taping or recording his or her lecture?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/30682/546)

Comment: I do have problem with what you say "_The software in question does not record at all,_".  When it outputs texts, do you display it? Do you store it? Please clarify.

Comment: @scaaahu Sorry, I meant that the software doesn't record AUDIO, only the texts. The texts are then stored in google docs

Comment: @Freedo Then YES. Really, really, YES. How would you take to having your words recorded and put online without permission?

Comment: @JessicaB Well, google docs is "online" but it is not public at all, so what is the difference of having it locally on your phone/pc ?

Comment: @Freedo No data has ever been accessed without permission from a 'safe' online space...

Comment: @Freedo FYI, when you put text on google docs, you [grant](https://www.google.com/policies/terms/) Google a *worldwide license to use, host, store, reproduce, modify, create derivative works (such as those resulting from translations, adaptations or other changes we make so that your content works better with our Services), communicate, publish, publicly perform, publicly display and distribute such content.* (although *The rights you grant in this license are for the limited purpose of operating, promoting, and improving our Services, and to develop new ones.*)  So "not public" is debatable.

Comment: @JessicaB, you should mark sarcasm more clearly, some people have the respective sense completely absent.

Comment: The only possible answer is that it is **not** allowed to record what is said without *explicit* permission. Same, just stronger, applies to sharing it. As  @FedericoPoloni's comment states, you *are* sharing with Google and giving them wide permission to use the recording, and that is an even bigger no-no.

Answer (score 6):

Yes.

It is always polite to ask anyone for permission before acting towards them in a way that clearly differs from what is generally taken as the norm.

I'm curious what you see as the argument against doing so, given you ask about etiquette.

Comment: I suspected that the teacher wouldn't want records of what they spoke without a lot of preparation like you do in lectures, and worried that I could leak it for revenge or things like that

Comment: @Freedo Exactly.

Comment: @Freedo For an extreme case, I could imagine a situation where a medical lecture is teaching about a very rare condition, and they are allowed to discuss cases within the lecture because it's necessary to protect people with the condition, but that private information should not be generally released because that could identify someone's medical history.

Comment: @Freedo that is an excellent reason for asking them in advance. The answer may be no, but the consequences could be worse if they discover you were recording them without permission.

Answer (score 5):

I think that you should indeed ask. Depending on your country / institution normally either the lecturer or the University owns the copyright to the oral presentation, and I suspect it is immaterial whether you record his voice signal or the spoken words.